# stripping a line with proper indent in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

INPUT:

```
$target: ENSG00000097007|ABL1
length: 3075
miRNA : hsa-miR-203
length: 22

mfe: -30.5 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.606919

position:  2745
target 5'   C             G     C 3'
             GUGGUCCUGGACA   CAC    
             CACCAGGAUUUGU   GUG    
miRNA  3' GAU             AAA     5'
```

I have to strip the last two lines and then assign it two arrays and read each character and obtain a ouput as shown down,

After stripping the line should be in the format :

```
   CACCAGGAUUUGU   GUG    
GAU             AAA
```

and if the line character is read from the line1 then it should be printed in lower case and if it is from the second line then it should be in upper case

the final output of the program should be 
"GAUcaccaggauuuguAAAgug"

the code with which we tried to read it did not strip the lines in perfect alignment as seen in the input

here the code we used:

```
 import fileinput
 import sys
 from sys import argv
 script, filename = argv
 file = open(filename)
 og1 = "AGUUCCUUUGUUUUGGUGACUG"
 pattern = "              "
 pattern1 = "miRNA  3'"
 file = open(filename)
 for line in file:
    if line.startswith(pattern):
        n = file.next()
        # print n[9:],#  bound mirna
        for i in range(0, len(og1)):
            print og1[i],
        print "\n" 
        for j in range(0,len(n)):
            print n[j],'
```

still further input for the problem

```
target: ENSG00000142208|ENST00000349310|AKT1
length: 992
miRNA : hsa-miR-125b-5p
length: 22

mfe: -23.9 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.610132

position  168
target 5' C     C               A 3'
           CGCAG   GGGGU   AGGGA    
           GUGUU   UCCCA   UCCCU    
miRNA  3' A     CAA     GAG       5'


target: ENSG00000142208|ENST00000349310|AKT1
length: 992
miRNA : hsa-miR-149-3p
length: 21

mfe: -36.6 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.598318

position  798
target 5' C   UGUC     AGG        G 3'
           CGC    GCCCC   CCCUCCCU    
           GUG    CGGGG   GGGAGGGA    
miRNA  3' C   U        GCA          5'


target: ENSG00000142208|ENST00000349310|AKT1
length: 992
miRNA : hsa-miR-185-5p
length: 22

mfe: -27.8 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.606550

position  733
target 5' C       CUCCC   CAGAUGA        C 3'
           CGGGAGC     CCU       UCUCUCCA    
           GUCCUUG     GGA       AGAGAGGU    
miRNA  3' A       AC      A                5'


target: ENSG00000142208|ENST00000349310|AKT1
length: 992
miRNA : hsa-miR-199a-3p
length: 22

mfe: -21.9 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.611970

position  357
target 5' C      CC   CCU      U    C 3'
           AGCCAG   GC   GGGCUG CUGU    
           UUGGUU   CG   UCUGAU GACA    
miRNA  3' A      ACA                  5'


target: ENSG00000142208|ENST00000349310|AKT1
length: 992
miRNA : hsa-miR-451a
length: 21

mfe: -21.2 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.612523

position  416
target 5' C      UCAACC       A     3'
           CUCAGU      UGGUGGC        
           GAGUCA      ACCAUUG        
miRNA  3' U      UU           CCAAA 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open(filename)                                          
for segment in file.read().split("\n\ntarget"):                          
    interested_lines = segment.split('\n')[-3:-1]  #Fetch last two lines 
    split1 = interested_lines[0].split()                                 
    split2 = interested_lines[1].split()[2:-1]                           
    for i in range(0,len(split1)<len(split2)):                           
        split1.append("")                                                

    req = ""                                                             
    for i in range(0,len(split2)):                                       
        req += split2[i]+split1[i].lower()                               
    for j in range(i+1,len(split1)):                                     
        req += split1[j]                                                 
    print req
```

**output**

```
AguguuCAAucccaGAGucccu
CgugUcggggGCAgggaggga
AguccuugACggaAagagaggu
AuugguuACAcgUCUGAUGACA
UgagucaUUaccauugCCAAA
```

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly this line means print split2[0]+split1[0].lower()+split2[1]+split1[1].lower()  I am newbie to python can't get the code

Comment: And i wish to say the input will be not be the same for all .. Like in other case the input is entirely different . So i need to know how to print like if it reads from the first line means it is in lowercase and if from the second line means it is upper case and in the final output in the single file as above @Ashoka Lella

Comment: @ramko, split() function splits the line based on spaces. For last-but one line split1 = ["CACCAGGAUUUGU","GUG"]. For last line split2 = ["miRNA", "3'", "GAU", "AAA", "5'"].

Comment: @ramko, If you could paste more content of your inputfile. I can generalize the code further

Comment: have added the input in question itselfd

Answer (score 0):

I'd split by lines, grab the last two, then iterate over both lines zipped together and use the character that's not a `" "`!

```
def combinebases(base_data):
    lines = base_data.splitlines()[-2:]
    output = list()
    lines[0] = lines[0].lower()
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(*lines):
        output.append(max(ch1, ch2))
    return ''.join(output[10:-4])
```

Possibly a safer result would be to return:

```
    return re.search("(?<=miRNA  3' )[augc]+", ''.join(output), re.I).group()
```

However the regex is overkill if every one of your base lengths is the same.

Results in:

```
>>> txt = """$target: ENSG00000097007|ABL1
length: 3075
miRNA : hsa-miR-203
length: 22

mfe: -30.5 kcal/mol
p-value: 0.606919

position:  2745
target 5'   C             G     C 3'
             GUGGUCCUGGACA   CAC    
             CACCAGGAUUUGU   GUG    
miRNA  3' GAU             AAA     5'"""

>>> combinebases(txt)
'GAUcaccaggauuuguAAAgug'
```